# SQL Server 2008 r2 Management Studio problems

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2, ssms

I've been using Management Studio with no problems on my current machine for just about two years, and successfully migrated to Windows 10 a few weeks back. Last week it started hanging on open with the following error:

```
Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.RegisteredServers.RegisteredServerException: 
Unable to read the list of previously registered servers on this system. 
Re-register your servers in the 'Registered Servers' window.
```

After doing some research, I managed to get around this by following the advice found in [this post](http://blog.sqltechie.com/2011/01/problem-in-opening-registered-servers.html), but now the object explorer refuses to expand. The program acts for all the world as if it is not responding, but eventually I'll get the following error:

Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: viewInfo (Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.SqlStudio.Explorer)

After that, I can open a new query window and everything responds, but I cannot use the object explorer. I've looked at [this thread](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sqlserver/en-US/7e0287b3-cd37-408e-8145-4b9dba8c7811/value-cannot-be-null-in-2008-r2-ssms-studio-package-failed-to-load?forum=sqltools), but it doesn't seem to solve anything for me.

Is there **ANY** chance I don't have to reinstall SSMS?

**Update:** Attempted to just reinstall, but failed with the error `"The specified account already exists"`.

Comment: Based on the post you linked to, do you think you have a corrupt `regsvr.xml` file?  That should be pretty easy to rebuild if that's the case. Uninstall/Reinstall of SSMS wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: Well, I removed the old file (renamed it to `regsvr-old.xml`), which is what got me to the SECOND problem (variable can't be null error).

Answer (score 0):

I received the same error message as you did, yesterday, Sept. 30, 2015, when I tried opening my trusty SQL Server 2008 R2 Management Studio.

After researching and trying the same things you mentioned, to no avail, I was about to try re-installing SSMS (which makes me shudder just thinking about it).

I know I had made no system changes recently, but perhaps Microsoft had changed my system recently?
Because a restore point is made automatically by Windows 7 whenever a system change is made, it naturally makes one whenever Microsoft performs a Critical Update. Below can be seen a change made to my system by Microsoft:

[image]

And there, above, I see that a Windows Update was done 9/29/2015, the day before my troubles began. And I had not used SSMS until 9/30/2015, and that's when I got the error message that you describe. Circumstantial evidence, if you will.

I learned the hard way 5 years ago that re-installing SQL Server 2008/2008 R2 is fraught with great pitfalls and risk everywhere you turn.

So now that I've seen the coincidence of the Windows Update, I've decided to wait a few more days to see if Microsoft will come out with a fix, or perhaps your thread will receive increased attention.

Steps to see your view Restore Points:

1. Control Panel\All Control Panel Items\System
2. Then in left panel choose System protection.
3. Click button System Restore...
4. Click button Next

Also one more clue is the following link, which says such an error message can occur when a User profile become corrupted: 
http://www.sqlserverf1.com/tag/microsoft-net-framework-error-unable-to-read-the-list-of-previously-registered-servers-on-this-system/

Comment: This morning I went to use the Restore Point shown above, but it was gone.  This unfortunately suggests to me that a virus or malware may possibly be involved in this issue, since some viruses deliberately delete restore points to prevent user from recovering.

Answer (score -1):

I got the same error but it pointed to my temp folder and wanted a subdirectory under there that had been cleared out.

In my case C:\Users<username>\AppData\Local\Temp\10\

Check the detailed error to see if that is the case for you.